# I am trying to make a simple rogue like in c# console app for practice and can't figure out how to add various Effects to items

Tags: c#

I want to instantiate a new item and give it a single effect from a pool of already established effects.

For example, I want to create a HealthPotion with the 
name "health potion"
and an effect that heals a given entity/actor for # amount of health.

The Entity class:

```
class Entity
    {
        public string Name;
        public float Health;
        public List<Item> items;

        public Entity(string name, float health, List<Item> items)
        {
            Name = name;
            Health = health;
            this.items = items;
        }
    }
```

The Item class:

```
class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public Effects effect;

        public Item(string name, Effects effect)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.effect = effect;
        }
    }
```

The Effects class:

```
class Effects
    {
        public static void Heal(Entity entity, float amount)
        {
            entity.Health += amount;
            Console.WriteLine($"{entity.Name} gained {amount} health");
        }
    }
```

The Main Program:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Entity Player = new Entity("Main Player", 50);
            Item potion = new Item("health potion", Effects.Heal(Player, 25));
            List<Item> itemsOnPlayer = new List<Item>();
            itemsOnPlayer.Add(potion);
            Player.items = itemsOnPlayer;
        }
```

I know I'm doing something really wrong but I have no clue what to do to get this to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cold model Effect as an `[Action<Entity>][1]`

```
    class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public Action<Entity> Effect;

        public Item(string name, Action<Entity> effect)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.Effect = effect;
        }
    }
```

then

```
Item potion = new Item("health potion", Player => Effects.Heal(Player, 25));
```

Comment: I want to ask as well if I want to add the item in the Players 'inventory' and then use it later on using this setup how would I go about doing that?